# External link to see Swagger docs for azure function?

Tags: azure-functions

If I have an Azure function:  http://foo.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/bar

What is the url for viewing the Swagger documentation that I created in the API definition table on the azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a link available in the Api Definition page in the Azure Portal. The URL will look something like:

https://foo.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/swagger?code=abcdefghijk==

The link is on the left panel of the Api Definition page. You may have to click the "Expand/Collapse" button in order to toggle it.

Edit: Misunderstood the question -- there is currently no way to view the 'Documentation' page publicly. I've filed https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2733 to track this.

Comment: if you mean the "API definition URL", I know about that.  That just shows the raw JSON.   I want to know if there is a public URL that will show the UI I see on the right-hand side of the API definition page.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Updated my answer.

Comment: OK. THanks for the update.   FYI, I ended up creating my own solution to generate/display swagger docs from azure functions:   https://www.nuget.org/packages/RocketScience.Azure.Functions/